# How can I create an incoming webhook via ReadTheDocs API?

Tags: read-the-docs

I am aware that you can create and delete incoming webhooks using the ReadTheDocs UI (for GitHub, GitLab, etc. integration), but I need to be able to do this without accessing the UI to automate the process. Is this possible? Or will webhook management be added to the API soon?

Answer (score 1):

The [API v3 documentation](https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/v3.html) does not list an endpoint to add an integration. Therefore, at the moment this is not possible.

For feature requests, it's better to [open an issue](https://github.com/readthedocs/readthedocs.org/issues/) upstream.

Comment: xref: https://github.com/readthedocs/readthedocs.org/issues/8581